# Avoid relation with itself in Django

Tags: django

I'm making a Twitter clone as a class project. I have a Profile model and I want to make the relationship between two of them. I did the following and it's working ok:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='following')
```

Now, how can I do to avoid a Profile relating with itself (a user following himself)?

I tried using clean, but it's not working.

```
    def clean_followers(self):
        self.followers.remove(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what is best for your project is to keep it as it is, even further, I'd enforce that every user is following itself, because when you show the main page's tweets, you´ll want the user to see their own. If you manage to accomplish what you want, you´ll have to do 2 separates queries (or at least an uglier one) to get all the tweets.

You can clean the "followers list" with very simple template tagging.

```
{% for follower_profile in current_profile.followers %}
    {% ifnotequal current_profile follower_profile %}
        <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
    {% endifnotequal %}
{% endfor %}
```